# How to make the number of ordered list disappear if there is no text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

I have an ordered list like this :

```
  <ol class="top-assignee">
            <li class ="1st-assignee"></li>
            <li class ="2nd-assignee"></li>
            <li class="3rd-assignee"></li>
            <li class="4th-assignee"></li>
            <li class="5th-assignee"></li>
        </ol>
```

Then , in my js file , i use jquery to append the information to corresponding element. For example , for the 1st element :

```
$.getJSON(link, function (details) {
        $(/* somedata get from json*/).appendTo(".1st-assignee");
    });
```

The same for the other 4 elements with different json link.

However , my problem is there is some link , they return null ( no data or link may expired ) --> There is no text to append to that element. But in this case , the number order still there. Look like this for example :

```
1.Jane
2.Jake
3.
4.Josh
5.
```

Is there anyway to remove the number if there is no text . so that i can become :

```
1.Jane
2.Jake
3.Josh
```

Update : thanks for your guys advice , however , one problem is i use json to get data and it takes quite long time , therefore , it will delete all the list element before it append

Comment: add if condition before append to check whether value is present or not

Comment: Why not check whether there's data before appending the element? If the element is there, the browser will render the number.

Comment: Use `:empty()` selector

Answer (score 2):

You use `each()` method and check if any `li` element is empty:

```js
$("#second > li").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="top-assignee">
    <li class ="1st-assignee">Jane</li>
    <li class ="2nd-assignee">Jake</li>
    <li class="3rd-assignee"></li>
    <li class="4th-assignee">Josh</li>
    <li class="5th-assignee"></li>
</ol>
<br>
<ol id="second" class="top-assignee">
    <li class ="1st-assignee">Jane</li>
    <li class ="2nd-assignee">Jake</li>
    <li class="3rd-assignee"></li>
    <li class="4th-assignee">Josh</li>
    <li class="5th-assignee"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thanks for your advice , however , one problem is i use json to get data and it takes quite long time , therefore , it will delete all the list element before it append

Answer (score 2):

Use [:empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

```js
$('.top-assignee li:empty').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="top-assignee">
  <li class="1st-assignee">1</li>
  <li class="2nd-assignee"></li>
  <li class="3rd-assignee">2</li>
  <li class="4th-assignee"></li>
  <li class="5th-assignee">3</li>
</ol>
<ol class="top-assignee">
  <li class="1st-assignee">1</li>
  <li class="2nd-assignee"></li>
  <li class="3rd-assignee">2</li>
  <li class="4th-assignee"></li>
  <li class="5th-assignee">3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thanks for your advice , however , one problem is i use json to get data and it takes quite long time , therefore , it will delete all the list element before it append

Comment: then fix the problem in the json or in generating the json not in the UI :)

Comment: thanks for the idea of using hide() and show() . I found out how to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display` property of list elements `li` to `none` if the data is not available.

The ordered list will render the correct order itself.

See the example below.

```js
// Sample Data
var data = ['Jane','Jake','','Josh',''];
// Capture all the list elements in an array
var li = $('.top-assignee li');
// Iterate the data
data.forEach((d, i) => {
  if(d) { // Check if data is non-empty
    li[i].innerHTML = d; // Update the list
  } else {
    li[i].style.display = 'none'; // Hide the element if no data.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol class="top-assignee">
    <li class ="1st-assignee"></li>
    <li class ="2nd-assignee"></li>
    <li class="3rd-assignee"></li>
    <li class="4th-assignee"></li>
    <li class="5th-assignee"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your advices , i realize i can do it using jquery getJSON success and error handle . Ill post here for someone who needs

```
 $.getJSON(link).then(function (details) {
        $("some text")
            .appendTo(".5th-assignee");
        console.log("Fifth success");
        $('.5th-assignee').show();
    },function(){
        console.log("Fifth fail");
        $('.5th-assignee').hide();
    });
```